# Ignore a feature on pre condition

Tags: junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

My feature has 4-5 scenarios, all are dependent on fact that certain element is present on page or not. For example username, password field.

How can I skip/ignore entire feature based on this condition.Some like below that I have written for skipping a scenario.

```
public void skipScenario(String message, Scenario scenario){
        if (username==null){
        Assume.assumeTrue(false);
      }
    }
```

Just like `Scenario` interface , we have `Feature` class with several implementations, I don't know which one can has the function to skip it.

[image]

Comment: You can of course do what you propose.  But why would you want to?  You have to explicitly state the input data for each scenario so you know at scenario definition time that username is null.  Simply have a separate scenario for that case if you need to test that the application responds correctly. See [cucumber anti-patterns](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2016/06/22/cucumber-antipatterns).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/community/faq/#how-can-i-make-cucumber-conditionally-skip-steps): "Each scenario should test one thing and fail for one particular reason. This means there should be no reason to skip steps.

If there does seem to be a reason you’d want to skip steps conditionally, you probably have an anti-pattern. For instance, you might be trying to test multiple things in one scenario or you might not be in control of the state of your test environment or test data.

The best thing to do here is to fix the root cause."